# React unnecessary rerender inside .map loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm try to implement airplane seat map and my Seat component inside loop rerenders, but I can't figure out why.

There is code:

```
export interface Props {
    passengers: PassengerState[];
    row: RowWithParts;
    nextRow: RowWithParts;
    rowIndex: number;
    lastRow: number;
    onSelect: (seat: SeatType) => void;
    highlightedService: string; // <- Seats rerenders when i change this prop, I'm try to avoid this
    setHighlightedService: (serviceId: string) => void;
    passengerId: string;
    segmentId: string;
}

const Row: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = React.memo(({ row, ...props }) => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.rowIndex === 0 && (
                <div className={cn(theme.row, theme.row_serviceClass)}>
                    {t(`${firstSeatService ? firstSeatService.serviceClass : 'Economy'} class`)}
                </div>
            )}

            {!isLastRow && row.exitRow && <ExitRow />}
            <div
                className={cn(theme.row, {
                    [theme.row_otherClass]: props.rowIndex === 0,
                    [theme.row_nextRowHasOtherClass]: nextRowHasOtherServiceClass(row, props.nextRow)
                })}
                with-wings={row.wing ? 'true' : 'false'}
            >
                {row &&
                    row.parts &&
                    row.parts.map((part, partIndex) => {
                        // omit some logic here

                        return (
                            <div
                                key={partIndex}
                                onMouseEnter={() => {
                                    // returns null for free seats and service for paid
                                    // in other cases like aisles returns boolean
                                    props.setHighlightedService(currentPartService) <-- change highlightedService prop here;
                                }}
                                onMouseLeave={() => props.setHighlightedService('')}
                            >
                                <div
                                    className={cn(theme.row__seatWrapper)} // <-- here is we highlight sibling div, I'm omit some code here
                                />

                                {part.map((seat, seatIndex) => {
                                    // some Seat logic ( calculate availability etc. )


                                    return (
                                        <Seat // <-- React.memo ( this component doesn't need to rerender when highlightedService changes)
                                            key={seatIndex}
                                            seat={seat}
                                            isOccupied={isOccupied}
                                            isAvailable={isAvailable}
                                            occupiedBy={occupiedBy}
                                            isOccupiedByOtherPassenger={isOccupiedByOtherPassenger}
                                            onSelect={props.onSelect}
                                        />
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
            </div>
            {isLastRow && row.exitRow && <ExitRow />}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
});

export default Row;
```

As I know, React should rerender only Row and div with class row__seatWrapper, but, I see that Seat component rerenders too, can you explain please what i missed?

Do I need to add custom prev/nextProps compare function to memoized Seat component ?

**Update**

```
(prevProps, nextProps) => { // <-- propsAreEqual callback of Seat.tsx
    console.log(prevProps === nextProps); // <-- false ???
    for (const [prop] of Object.entries(prevProps)) {
        if (prevProps[prop] !== nextProps[prop]) {
            console.log(prop); // <-- doesn't log anything
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, when a key in parent object changes it will trigger re-render of the whole render function which depends on it.
Since we have added key in the looped map, there should not be any delay in rerender.

Comment: Probably you have defined inline function for onSelect which is why your component renders everytime

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no, for now i'm just pass onSelect={null} but, when I console.log(prevProps === nextProps) of Seat component, it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like unnecessary rerenders occurs when ThemeProvider changes

```
export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<ThemeProviderProps> = React.memo(({ value, children }) => {
    const theme: EngineTheme = useContext(ThemeContext);

    return <ThemeContext.Provider value={mergeCSS(theme, value)}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>;
});
```

because Seat.tsx get its theme from that context :(